# Using XMLHttpRequest() PUT with GAE Python

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest, put

I am currently trying to write some Javascript to interact with an API that I deployed on GAE (using Python) using XMXMLHttpRequest(). I've had no issue getting a GET, however the PUT is giving me a lot of trouble.

Interestingly, I have no issue touching the PUT request from a test HTTP site (https://www.hurl.it/), however I receive a status value of 0 every time I try from my own Javascript code. Below are snippets of my GAE and Javascript code.

(NOTE - I must use a "put" for this call as a requirement.)

Any guidance would be appreciated!

GAE (Server):

```
def put(self):

# Save variables for update
cardkey = self.request.get('key', default_value=None)
ident = self.request.get('ident', default_value=None)
brand = self.request.get('brand', default_value=None)
year = self.request.get('year', default_value=None)
player = self.request.get('player', default_value=None)

# If card key is provided then update card
if cardkey:
  # Get card
  card_to_update = ndb.Key(db_models.Card, int(cardkey)).get()
  if ident:
    card_to_update.ident = ident
  if brand:
    card_to_update.brand = brand
  if year:
    card_to_update.year = year
  if player:
    card_to_update.player = player
  # Save changes and print update to requester
  card_to_update.put()
  card_dict_format = card_to_update.to_dict()
  self.response.write(json.dumps(card_dict_format))
  return

# If card key is not provided send error
else:
  self.response.write('key not provided. must provide key for update.')
  return
```

And the Javascript from my webpage:

```
      <script>
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = 'http://cs496-assignment3-mastrokn.appspot.com/updatecard';
            var param = 'key=5636318331666432';
            myRequest.open('put', url);


            myRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if ((myRequest.readyState == 4) && (myRequest.status == 200))
                {
                    // var myArr = JSON.parse(myRequst.responseText);
                    // myFunction(myArr);
                    document.getElementById("viewCards").innerHTML = myRequest.status;

                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("viewCards").innerHTML = myRequest.status;
                }
            }

            myRequest.send(param); 
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `onreadystatechange()` handler should look like this:

```
  myRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (myRequest.readyState == 4) //Don't do anything until the readyState==4
    {
      if(myRequest.status == 200)  //Check for status==200
      {
          document.getElementById("viewCards").innerHTML = myRequest.status;
      }
      else //All other status codes
      {
          document.getElementById("viewCards").innerHTML = 
            'readyState=' 
            + myRequest.readyState 
            + ' status='  
            + myRequest.status
            + ' status text='
            + myRequest.statusText;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

> If you end up with an XMLHttpRequest having status=0 and
>   statusText=null, it means that the request was not allowed to be
>   performed. It was UNSENT.

To see what went wrong, check the `javascript console` in your browser for an error, e.g.:

> [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://cs496-assignment3-mastrokn.appspot.com/updatecard. Origin
>   http://localhost:4567 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   (4.htm, line 0)

When I run the code above and send the XMLHttpRequest to my own local server, the PUT request succeeds with a status code of 200.

Lastly, I have doubts about the server code you posted because I don't know of any framework where you return None from a request handler--rather you return some string or a response object.  Yet, using other means to make a PUT request to your url returns a 200 status code. Is that really your server code?  What framework are you using?